# MySQL stored procedure with variable table name and retrieving missing records

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

What I want to achieve is a stored procedure that returns a record set of all missing id's in a table.
For example:

```
--------------------
| games            |
--------------------
| id | game name   |
--------------------
|  1 | first game  |
|  2 | second game |
|  5 | fifth game  |
| 10 | tenth game  |
-------------------
```

This should result in:

```
----------
| result |
----------
| 3      |
| 4      |
| 6      |
| 7      |
| 8      |
| 9      |
----------
```

Note that there are multiple tables that can be processed, so I would like to have only one stored procedure that needs maintenance, so the table name should be added dynamically.

I have found several tutorials on prepared statements, parameters and loops in stored procedure, but I don't get the combination to work.

The logic I have in mind to apply is:

1. get the highest id of in the table
2. loop through the table and check if the iterator is present as id
3. if not, add to the result set and return the result set after looping is done

This is what I got so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_missing_ids`(IN in_kind varchar(15), OUT out_result int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE highest_id INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE check_id INT;

    SET @highestid =  CONCAT("(CALL get_highest_id('", in_kind, "',@id)");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @highestid;
    SET highest_id = (EXECUTE stmt1);

    WHILE i < highest_id DO
        SET @checkid = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", in_kind, " WHERE id = ", i, ")");
        PREPARE stmt2 FROM @checkid;
        SET check_id = (EXECUTE stmt2);
        IF check_id = 0 THEN
            SELECT i;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;    
END
```

Who can explain me how I can get this combo to work?

Comment: what do you have so far

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Here is my spec so please do it

Comment: @Drew, I have added the code that I currently have

Comment: Fair enough. I retracted my close vote ... let us know if you still need help as I am sure I can solve this for you if the guys below don't

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to loop at all. You just need to join your source table with a temporary (or fixed) table containing sequenced number and compare them.

To make it as stored procedure that takes table name and ID of that table, please try this stored procedure. It works on mine.

```
delimiter $$

use `test`$$

drop procedure if exists `FindMissedID`$$

create definer=`root`@`localhost` procedure `FindMissedID`(tableName varchar(100), tableNameID varchar(100))
begin

-- Create temporary table containing number for comparing source table
drop table if exists ListOfNumber;
create temporary table ListOfNumber(
    number int, 
    primary key (number)
)
engine = innodb;

-- Generate some numbers. Make it fit your needs
insert into ListOfNumber
    select @row := @row + 1 as row from 
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) tens,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) hundreds,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) thousands,
    -- etc
    (select @row:=0) r;

-- Make a prepared statement
set @SQL = concat("select ListOfNumber.number as MissingID"
        , char(10), "from ", tableName
        , char(10), "right join ListOfNumber on ", tableName, ".", tableNameID, " = ListOfNumber.number"
        , char(10), "where ", tableName, ".", tableNameID, " is null"
        , char(10), "order by ListOfNumber.number"
            );

-- Execute statement                
prepare statement from @SQL;
execute statement;
deallocate prepare statement;               

end$$

delimiter ;
```

Give it a try.

Comment: this is getting close, but I want to find the missing ID's until the highest ID is checked from that table, I have another stored procedure for that: get_highest_id(in_tablename, out_highestid).
How would that work then?

Comment: Btw, why do you want to find the highest ID? I tried that SP and it display all of missing ID from my table, just have to make sure the max number of temporary table is higher than max ID of your table. If this don't address your problem enough, could you elaborate more?

Comment: The reason is as follows: at the moment, one table can be 300 records long, but within a year 4000 (for example), this means that at this point the largest id is for example 320 (with 20 missing records) en within a year 4100 (with 100 missing records). I want a list of all the missing numbers in the range from zero to the largest id present at this point in time. I don't want to know and enter the length of the largest id when I check for missing id's, if I can make myself clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Using some tips from [this](http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/), you can use a single query to find the missing ids:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_missing_ids`()
BEGIN

    SELECT (t1.id + 1) as missing_starts_at, 
           (SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 
             FROM games t3 
             WHERE t3.id > t1.id
            ) as missing_ends_at
    FROM games t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id 
                       FROM games t2 
                       WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1)
    HAVING missing_ends_at IS NOT NULL;
END//
```

That will return rows with as ranges:

```
call `get_missing_ids`();
+-------------------+-----------------+
| missing_starts_at | missing_ends_at |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 3 |               4 |
|                 6 |               9 |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Now you can use that values.